# How to configure MAX11647

Tags: i2c, wiringpi

I am using this i2c 10 bit ADC for temperature sensing and battery level sensing with the Raspberry Pi.

What is the correct way to configure this device?
 I tried writing the values `0x82` to the setup byte and `0x21` to the config byte.

It's always showing me `0xfc` or `0xff`.

Here is the wiring diagram:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
int file_i2c;
int length;
unsigned int buffer[60] = {0};

 int main(){

//----- OPEN THE I2C BUS -----
char *filename = (char*)"/dev/i2c-1";
if ((file_i2c = open(filename, O_RDWR)) < 0)
{
    //ERROR HANDLING: you can check errno to see what went wrong
    printf("Failed to open the i2c bus");
    return;
}


int addr = 0x36;          //<<<<<The I2C address of the slave
if (ioctl(file_i2c, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave.\n");
    //ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong
    return;
}


//----- WRITE BYTES -----
//buffer[0] = 0x08; // HS mode
buffer[0] = 0x82; //setup byte
buffer[1] = 0x61; //config byte

length = 2;         //<<< Number of bytes to write
if (write(file_i2c, buffer, length) != length)      //write() returns the number of bytes actually written, if it doesn't match then an error occurred (e.g. no response from the device)
{
    /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
    printf("Failed to write to the i2c bus.\n");
}

//----- READ BYTES -----
length = 2;         //<<< Number of bytes to read
if (read(file_i2c, buffer, length) != length)       //read() returns the number of bytes actually read, if it doesn't match then an error occurred (e.g. no response from the device)
{
    //ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed
    printf("Failed to read from the i2c bus.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Data read: %x\n", buffer);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The datasheet for the device will tell you the configuration needed.

Comment: I did everything as per the data sheet. Still no hope

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you used, and a wiring diagram...

Comment: KennetRunner , I've edited the question to add what you asked for.

Comment: I know you were asked for a diagram but a photo would be more useful.  All a diagram does is tell us what you plan to do, a photo shows what you have done.  Similarly a code snippet leaves us guessing as to what you are doing.  A complete program would be better.  Your snippet is sending 0x00 0x82 to the device.  What is that meant to do?

Comment: The circuit is part of a bigger circuit. It's a single board now. `0x82` and `0x61` are the setup byte and config byte we are writing into the ADC(as per data sheet) . And that's the complete program.

Comment: No, it is not the complete program.  It does not compile.  Again I point out the snippet is sending 0x00 0x82 to the device, not 0x82 0x61,

Comment: Oh it should be `buffer[0] = 0x82; buffer[1] = 0x61;` Now it would sent 0x82 and 0x61 , as we can see in the oscilloscope

Comment: The code is compiling and working for me Joan. I can even see the waveform